# Unable to create a infowindow on the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);//Code for one marker

        if (type == 'CONTROLLER') 
        {
            mark = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: point,
                title: name,
                map: map,
                icon: "MapImages/controller.png"
            });

        }
function infowindow() //Code for InfoWindow

    {
        var i = 0;
        var j=0;
        var k=0;
        var l=0;
        var m = 0;
        var text =.....;
        alert(text);
        var AJAX = ob_create();
        alert("hello");
        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function () 
            {
            alert(AJAX.readyState);
            if (AJAX.readyState == 4 || AJAX.readyState == "complete") 
                 {
                document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = AJAX.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].firstChild[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("j").innerHTML = AJAX.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("add")[j].firstChild[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = AJAX.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("mac")[k].firstChild[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("l").innerHTML = AJAX.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("lat")[l].firstChild[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = AJAX.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("long")[m].firstChild[0].nodeValue;
            }
            var url = 'Map3.aspx?Text=' +text.toString();
            AJAX.open("Get", url, true);
            AJAX.send(null);
        }
    },
```

I have created custom markers and custom InfoWindow, above is my code,
In Infowindow I need to pass the mark from marker in variable text in string form so that I can pass it to aspx page in query string format,but it is taking as object and I am not able to solve this problem,any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = mark.getTitle();
```

Mark is the object for marker and `getTitle()` is the method of marker to get the name of the device passed to marker via database.